# C - sbrk(size) returns valid pointer but sbrk(0) is negative value

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, sbrk

My code for the allocation is

```
dat* data = NULL;
data = sbrk(SIZE);
if((int) data != -1){
   return data
}else{
  printf("Not enough space");
}
```

The sbrk(...) function returns a valid adress (0x603021) but when I go into gdb and and print sbrk(0) i get the get the hex value 0xffffffff8060341. After doing the math I figured out the pointer 0x8060341 should be sbrk(0). Where did the letter f's in front (i.e. 0xfffff...) come from?

Comment: Can you show us *exactly* what you did? How *precisely* did you get the value you're asking about?

Comment: More exactly how are you getting the value `0xffffffff8060341`? It looks like you're perhaps getting sign extension involved somewhere. Do you have any other weird `(int)` casts somewhere, perhaps? The one in the code you've currently posted is certainly invalid on 64-bit archs.

Comment: Also, have you properly included `unistd.h` and/or compiled with warnings? Your problem could conceivably be caused by an implicit declaration of `sbrk` as an `int (*)(int)`.

Comment: In gdb while debugging, I just typed in - p (void*) sbrk(0)  - and also unistd.h is declared

Comment: Don't describe what you did - show a short, working program and a transcript of a gdb session that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

gdb is showing you the full 64bit address of the memory segment. 64bit addresses in hexidecimal require 16 total hexidecimal digits (0-9,A-F) to fully specify. From 64bits/4bits per digit = 16.

If you are seeing fewer it is because the editor is truncating the first 32bits ( 8 hexidecimal digits ) of the memory address and only showing you the remaining or lower 8. This is a hangover from the 32bit computing world where 8 hexidecimal digits were sufficient to fully specify a memory address.

Comment: But for sbrk(0) the address should be 0x000000008060341 not 0xffffffff8060341

Comment: Is sbrk(0) returning -1 as an error indicator? Has brk(..) been called before sbrk(0)?

Comment: brk(..) is never called in the program

Comment: I'm not familiar with these calls and have never used them. The documentation suggests they are best avoided and as far as I read it, it seems to me for sbrk(..) to work brk(...) should have been called first. Doc example at: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk